# Logic for Symfony form filter field with more than one element

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I am implementing a **negation** filter field in Symfony 1.4. with 1 text input and 1 checkbox for negation.

I can access the input value as below

```
public function addXXXColumnQuery($query, $field, $value)
{
    $v = $value['text'];
    $n = 'negation_checkbox_true_or_false'; // don't know how?

    if ($n === true) 
    {
        $query->addWhere($query->getRootAlias().'.name = ?', $v);
    } 
    else if ($n === false) 
    {
        $query->addWhere($query->getRootAlias().'.name <> ?', $v);
    }
}
```

but I can't figure out how to access the checkbox value.

**sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable** has a 'with_delete' option that prints a checkbox. Anyone knows where is the code that checks for that value and delete the file?

If I can find that, maybe I can figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a `sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable` with the `with_delete` option set to *true*, the widget renders an additional checkbox which is named after the file upload widget with a "_delete" suffix.
When the checkbox is checked, the `sfParameterHolder` of the `sfWebRequest` object contains a parameter named after the checkbox widget.

So, suppose you have a `sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable` named "file". In your action, you can see if the delete checkbox is checked using:

```
$request->hasParameter('file_delete');
```

Comment: I don't think you should handle it in the action, but in the `doSave()` or `doUpdate()` action of the form.

Comment: Depending on the behaviour to implement, it's probably better.